# Error: "libavformat\avformat.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: cmake, ffmpeg, g++

I create a simple c++ file called `test.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libavformat\avformat.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

and using g++ in terminal to compile test.cpp file with the command:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
```

I get this error:

```
test.cpp:2:10: fatal error: libavformat\avformat.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <libavformat\avformat.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Notes:
`libavformat\avformat.h` path is: `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat/avformat.h`

and using ffmpeg version is:

```
$ ffmpeg -version

ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
```

Using this command:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags libavformat` test.cpp  `pkg-config --libs libavformat` -o test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a forward slash, since you are apparently on a Unix system:

```
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
```